# Why does is_a? fail to match type, and results in split throwing an exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

While running RSpec and FactoryGirl, it automatically converts any `:id` param into a fixnum, whereas, in real life, it gets passed as a string. Code I have that processes that `:id` as a composite primary key tries to call split on `params[:id]`. That results in an exception, like so:

```
NoMethodError:
    undefined method 'split' for 234:Fixnum
```

When trying to call something like this:

```
  @myinstance = MyClass.find(params[:id].split("-").map{|x| x.to_i})
```

In an attempt to get around this issue, I have added a simple type check:

```
if params[:id].is_a? Fixnum
  @myinstance = MyClass.find(params[:id])
else
  @myinstance = MyClass.find(params[:id].split("-").map{|x| x.to_i})
end
```

Yet, this does not work as I expect it to. The `if` statement evaluates to `false`, and the `split` is still attempted, resulting in the same error. How is it possible that Ruby recognizes `params[:id]` as a Fixnum in the "`else`" logic, yet fails to evaluate to `true` in the `if` statement?

Answer (score 3):

It's sheer logic: `params[:id]` is a `String` or `nil`.

Oh... I must edit my answer:

When you do controller specs, the params you send are sent `as-is` and not stringified...
That's a pain but it should be fixed sooner or later.

So in your specs, stringify your params to be closer to reality.

That's a really important point: don't adapt your code to your specs, do the opposite.

Comment: @muistooshort: hell yes, unfortunately, I learnt it the hard way: my specs were passing but my prod was crashing...

Comment: @muistooshort: that's sooooooo true ;)

Comment: If, as you say, params[:id] is a string, then how come the error states that it can't find the "split" method on fixnum?

Comment: oh correct, I didn't see everything... are you sure it breaks on this line? Does `params[:id].split("-")` breaks in your debugger?

Comment: It for sure breaks there. I'm in the middle of a dev env switch, so I don't have debugging capability at the moment (errors are coming from our CI server). However, I wrapped the call in a begin-rescue clause, and the behavior confirms it's this line.